# Bad scrolling in webpage powered by bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a webpage as shown [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9v7swaf/). I used external CDNs for all `css` and `js` libraries. 
I used `css` (my own css) like this:

```
#imgOne {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 35%;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    background-image: url(../images/Bistip-in-media.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}

#imgTwo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 45%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16%;
    background-image: url(../images/Skyline.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 6px -6px #777;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#formPos, #formPosOne {
    position: relative;
    width: 34%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 6px -6px #777;
    background-color: #166BB3;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 35%;
    background-color: #166bb3;
}  
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But whole page isn't scrolling. Only the part containing blue `div` is scrolling. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you want elements to scroll, don't use `position: fixed;`

Comment: You can fix that by removing `position: fixed`

Comment: Removing `position: fixed` would make footer to go up, thus messing up the whole UI

Comment: There are other ways to create [sticky footers](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/). Fixed elements do not scroll. You need to build your UI in a different way

Comment: Isn't it possible to add scrolling to whole page by maintaining same set of css rules where positions are optimized?

Answer (score 0):

This will make the content your main container scroll, but you'll need to position the container a little more

```
.containerA{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```